# How do I "smoothly" format HttpHandler URI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, httphandler, web-services

I'm just meddling in the ways of the RESTful web service in C# using ASP.Net 2.0 and have managed  (via a class library, a reference to dll produced by the former and some adjustment of my web.config) to coax out a URI format like so:

http: //localhost/DevelopmentProject/testhandler/?input=thisismyinput

Which unremarkably just returns the input as a piece of text with the enlightening prefix "Your Input Was: "

I was under the impression that I could get the URI to become further ensmoothened to something more along the lines of:

http: //localhost/DevelopmentProject/testhandler/thisismyinput

and have the same result but have no idea how to get rid of the pesky "?input="

The entry to the httphandlers section of my web.config is (spaces added so code displays):

< add verb="*" path="testhandler/*" type="HandlerLib.testhandler, HandlerLib"/ >

I am running IIS 5.1 on the local machine, will this introduce a problem?

Essentially where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I was just hoping there was some way of doing this naturally without additions but that urirewriter looks handy.

Comment: It's a great thing to implement into your site in general to handle this problem. I am however also waiting for a more natural solution to you question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda cheated.

Try:

[My Article About How I Got Round It](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RestServicesInASPNET2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use UrlRewriting to rewrite the Url to what you need.

I use http://urlrewriter.net/ to do all my rewriting, and you could setup something like this in your scenario

```
<rewriter>
   <rewrite 
     url="DevelopmentProject/testhandler/([\w]+)" 
     to="DevelopmentProject/testhandler/?input=$1" />
</rewriter>
```

This would remain "http: //localhost/DevelopmentProject/testhandler/thisismyinput" in your browser address bar, yet process as "http: //localhost/DevelopmentProject/testhandler/?input=thisismyinput"

Answer (score 0):

You could implement URL rewriting, using something like [URLRewriter.net](http://www.urlrewriter.net/)
That would let you use the syntax you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Change your config from:
   < add verb="" path="testhandler/" type="HandlerLib.testhandler, HandlerLib"/ >
to:
   < add verb="" path="testhandler/*" type="HandlerLib.testhandler, HandlerLib"/ >

Comment: I've just realised someone came in and edited my question so it was asked wrong. What a fool. I'm editing it back.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the value of Request.PathInfo in your handler's ProcessRequest function
with a URL like http://localhost/DevelopmentProject/testhandler/thisismyinput.

If that doesn't do it, make sure that IIS 5.1 is routing ALL requests to the aspnet_isapi.dll.  (Although, it seems like it already is)  This is the "Configuration..." button > "App Mappings" tab in your virtual directory in IIS.